# How do I prevent duplicate values in Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: duplicates, google-cloud-datastore

Is there any mechanism available to prevent duplicate data in certain fields of my entities?  Something similar to an SQL `unique`.

Failing that, what techniques do people normally use to prevent duplicate values?

Comment: Could you provide additional, specific details about your data model? Datastore doesn't support `unique` constraints on properties, there are alternative approaches but it is hard to recommend one without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ditto. Any chance you have more detail to share? If it's truly a unique identifier, a key name might be a good fit. If you want a "unique property", you can try using transactions, but that will likely cause performance problems for you pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do the equivalent on a `UNIQUE` constraint in SQL will not scale very well in a NoSQL storage system like Cloud Datastore. This is mainly because it would require a read before every write, and a transaction surrounding the two operations.

If that's not an issue (ie, you don't write values very often), the process might look something like:

1. Begin a serializable transaction
2. Query across all Kinds for a match of property = value
3. If the query has matches, abort the transaction
4. If there are no matches, insert new entity with property = value
5. Commit the transaction

Using [gcloud-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python), this might look like...

```
from gcloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()

with client.transaction(serializable=True) as t:
    q = client.query(kind='MyKind')
    q.add_filter('property', '=', 'value')

    if q.fetch(limit=1):
        t.rollback()
    else:
        entity = datastore.Entity(datastore.Key('MyKind'))
        entity.property = 'value'
        t.put(entity)
        t.commit()
```

Note: The `serializable` flag on `Transaction`s is relatively new in gcloud-python. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python/pull/1205/files for details.

---

The "right way" to do this is to design your data such that the key is your measure of "uniqueness", but without knowing more about what you're trying to do, I can't say much else.

Comment: this won't work if another entity with the same field value is new/recent and you don't receive it as result of your query - no get by key so no consistency, right? Don't you need a Map Entity as the next anwser suggests? Thanks

Comment: I believe that this is addressed in the section on transaction isolation and consistency. Specifically "Queries and lookups in a transaction see a consistent snapshot of the state of the database. This snapshot is guaranteed to contain the effect of all transactions and writes that completed prior to the beginning of the transaction." (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#isolation_and_consistency)

Comment: @JJGeewax but the query `q` and the call to `q.fetch()` are not using the transaction `t` at all, are you sure that simply running the code in the context manager would magically make all database-related statements executed in it be a part of a single transaction?

Answer (score 1):

The approach given above will not work in the datastore because you cannot to a query across arbitrary entities inside a transaction. If you try, an exception will be thrown.

However you can do it by using a new kind for each unique field and doing a "get" (lookup by key) within the transaction.

For example, say you have a Person kind and you want to ensure that Person.email is unique you also need a kind for e.g. UniquePersonEmail.  That does not need to be referenced by anything but it is just there to ensure uniqueness.

1. start transaction
2. get UniquePersonEmail with id = theNewAccountEmail
3. if exists abort
4. put UniquePersonEmail with id = theNewAccountEmail
5. put Person with all the other details including the email
6. commit the transaction

So you end up doing one read and two writes to create your account.